# Updating Field in RavenDB Document

Tags: c#, json, ravendb

Good day,

I have a RavenDB JSON Document in which one field ("Info") contains a string that looks like this:

```
"{\"value1\":\"9\", \"value2\": \"dog\", ....}"
```

I would like to remove the escaping `"\"` characters so it will be recognized as a JSON List by RavenDB.

However, I have tried updating the Documents with

`newString = oldString.Replace("\\", "")` ,

`newString = oldString.Replace(@"\", "")`

and `newString = oldString.Trim(new Char[] { @"\" })`

but it does not work. After applying these above mentioned methods the string looks unchanged.

Please see below the full code:

```
            while(true)
            {
                var result = session.Query<Documents>()
                    .Take(1000).Skip(i)
                    .ToList();
                if (result.Count == 0)
                    break;

                foreach (var r in result)
                {
                    string rInfo = r.Info.ToString();
                    rInfo = rInfo.Replace("\\", "");

                    PATCHED_Doc r_Doc = new PATCHED_Doc()
                    {
                        Info = rInfo, 
                        Value = "test",
                        Id = r.Id,
                        Date = r.Date,
                    };

                    session.Store(r_Doc);
                    session.SaveChanges();

                }

                session.SaveChanges();

                i += result.Count;
            }



public class PATCHED_Doc
{
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: Please post full code. Did you notice that you cannot change a string in .NET? They are immutable. You need to create a new one. The methods you called are doing just that, you might not have used the return value properly.

Comment: @nvoigt edited my question. hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Parse the JSON into an object and then hand it over to Raven DB. Strings are treated as strings. Use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library to [parse it into Anonymous objects](http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidHoerster/archive/2012/01/06/json.net-and-deserializing-anonymous-types.aspx).  Change your Info property to type of object. Then Assign the anonymous object to the Info property.

Comment: Thank you. Used Newtonsoft.Json.Linq to parse the string. However the Json Object does not appear to be saved correctly in RavenDB. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253014/ravendb-storing-json-object-c)