# RavenDB, storing Json Object (c#)

Tags: c#, json, ravendb

I am parsing a string variable into a Json Object with the following code:

```
string[] rInfo = r.Info.ToString().Split('|'); 
dynamic JSON_Obj = JObject.Parse(rInfo[0]);
```

And it is looking fine in the Code, meaning if i check the object at runtime it has the right contents. However, after i store it in RavenDB it looks like this:

```
{"street": {
    "$type": "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue, Newtonsoft.Json",
    "$values": []
},
"country": {
    "$type": "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue, Newtonsoft.Json",
    "$values": []
}}
```

For example in country should be something like "ES" or "GB".

I am storing the JSON Object as part of a document like this:

```
                PATCHED_Doc Doc = new PATCHED_Doc()
                {
                    Info = JSON_Obj, 
                    Value = "test",
                    Id = r.Id,
                    Date = r.Date,
                };

                session.Store(Doc);
                session.SaveChanges();
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to debug to see what actually JSON.NET parses your string to and why

Comment: In debugging it looks like this: `{"street":"Castelló", "country":"ES", ...}`. Same object, once saved, looks in RavenDB like described above...

Comment: @fahadash Forgot to address my comment above to you...

Comment: I think dynamic objects aren't a good idea. Either you map your types properly using JSON.NET attributes. If you can't map them, then try anonymous types.

Answer (score 0):

fahadash was right. I had to crate a class to map the attributes.

```
var JSON_Obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Infolist>(strJSON);
```

`Infolist` being:

```
public class Infolist
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string coutnry { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Like this it is working...